# Sketch: How to change the background color of an image?

Tags: sketch-app, color-conversion

I have a PNG I downloaded from the internet / shutterstock:
[image]

It's a PNG, however the background is white. Is there a way I could remove the white background in Sketch and replace it with a different color (e.g. purple)?

Ideally I'd like a tool similar to the Hue slider, but just for a specific color (white in this case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to get rid of the white is via channels in Photoshop. Take a look at them and decide which to use. Combine those with the best contrast.
Choose "Image/Calculations" (my screenshots show the german PS-Version)

[image: combine Channels in Photoshop]

Load the mask from the channels, and create a mask from the selection, maybe invert the mask. 
If you place the image on top of something else choose "Multiply" from the Blending Modes or something similar. This takes away the borders if the underlying image is darker.

[image: finished Mask]

Comment: wow this is awesome! i wish i had photoshop to do this...

Answer (score 2):

Sketch app is not built for photo editing, you'll have to use a photo editor like photoshop or gimp to do this.

You could use the edit tool to remove the background and place the image with a now transparent background on a colored block. However your image seems to have some blurred edges and I doubt this will look great.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you do:

- Select the image
- Click "Make exportable"
- Next to "presets" click slice (the knife icon)
- Now you can enable "background color"!
- Export to jpg

I found the solution [here](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understanding-sketchs-export-options--cms-22207)